# Hide Fields in Edit Page based on Role and Content Type?

Tags: users

Use Case: Content Editor A (Role of Monday)  when edting a node (of Content Type Alpha) is able to use Field AA and Field BB.

But Content Editor B (Role of Tuesday), when editing the same node, does not see Field AA and Field BB.

I have experimented with many of the modules of this regard (Field Permissions, Conditional Fields, Rules), but nothing that can compute for  all four conditions (role, content type, edit, fields).

Answer (score 1):

How does field permissions, custom permissions, not work for you?

[image]

> Example: Using field permisions, I am able to "hide" Field AA by not allowing Content Editor A (Role of Monday) to Edit, or View. But...it also hides the Field AA in Views. That's not what I want. The Editor should still be able to see the Field in any View.

[image]

In the above picture, Monday is not going to see the field when he edits the page, but will be able to see the field when its displayed by views.

This is the solution to the Example you provided. In your original question, it would be the role of Tuesday who needs to look like that.

Comment: Example: Using field permisions, I am able to "hide" Field AA by not allowing Content Editor A (Role of Monday) to Edit, or View. But...it also hides the Field AA in Views. That's not what I want. The Editor should still be able to see the Field in any View.

Comment: @SandsHakimi they can't see it because you are not allowing them to view it. You need to checkmark View Own Value and View any value. (see picture)

Comment: PS: please accept this answer, by clicking the green checkmark, if it answers/solves your question. Lookin at your profile I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to your questions.

Comment: After doing what you suggested the Field does appear in the View, BUT it also appears in the Edit page in a non-editable state. I don't want this role to see the field in the edit page.